# Android - displaying UTF-8 (russian) on device

Tags: java, android, unicode, utf-8

I'm debugging application on my android device (Motorola Defy, 2.1), the application gets Russian HTML page from network, but can't display it. It displays as [link text](http://habreffect.ru/files/a17/2bf565b01/DSC02569.jpg).
HTML page is in UTF-8 (100% sure). Source code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://m.rasp.yandex.ru/direction?direction=" + direction);
        httpget.setHeader("charset", "utf-8");
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        String html = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

What am I need for normal displaying of Russian text? Sorry for bad English knowledge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`httpget.setHeader("charset", "utf-8");` doesn't make any sense.

Encoding is determined by `BasicResponseHandler`. If response encoding is not specified in `Content-Type` header (as in your case), `BasicResponseHandler` assumes it to be `ISO-8859-1`, and it can't be configured.

So, you need to implement your own `ResponseHandler` that falls back to another default encoding, something like this:

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
    public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response)
        throws HttpResponseException, IOException {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(),
                    statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        return entity == null ? null : EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you should decode `String html` from CP-1251 or smth like that to UTF-8 (`html.setHeader()` - migth be ignored).

My suggestion would be to copy returned text (let say from LogCat) and place it into [ArtLebedev's decoder](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/). So you will know  original coding of HTML returned back from Yandex.

Comment: I researched, that OS trys to display UTF-8 in ISO8859-1. The contains of the response are in UTF-8 - it's 100%, with any header.